# ManytoMany objects access in template django

Tags: python, django

There are 2 objects with a many-to-many relationship, trying to access one in the template through the other and an error POPs up:

```
   NoReverseMatch at /decision/livingrooms/kitchen/provans/
Reverse for 'style' with keyword arguments '{'rmslg': 'bathroom', 'stslg': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['decision/livingrooms/(?P<rmslg>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<stslg>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

But bathroom styles is not empty

html:

```
{% for room in all_rooms %}
                <li class="menu__item menu__item_interiors"><a href="{% url 'decision:style' rmslg=room.slug stslg=room.styles.slug|first %}">{{ room.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
```